# In MySQL documentation, what is the scope of a "program"?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

In particular I'm reading about [exit handlers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/declare-handler.html) here:

> The handler_action value indicates what action the handler takes after execution of the handler statement:
>   CONTINUE: Execution of the current program continues.

What is the scope of "program" in this sentence?  I can ask more specific questions that this should answer:

- Must it be in a stored procedure or stored function?
- Does it apply just to the set of statements I'm executing, either via
  one `execute` statement in a driver such as JDBC, or run as a block
  in a program like MySQL Workbench?
- Is it the responsibility of the driver to delimit one program from another?

The only "clue" I have here is documentation for [declare](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/declare.html):

> DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements.

which at least implies the scope of a declared handler is tight, so this can't pollute a whole connection.

I'm framing this question so generally because I'm attempting to graduate from SQL 101 of selects, updates, inserts and deletes, into writing more complex, performance-aware tasks. But one stumbling block I'm finding is the very basics of what a MySQL program "is" besides a collection of statements are hard for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

A program as used here means the same thing as a "stored program."

> Stored programs include these objects:
>
> **Stored routines**, that is, **stored procedures** and **[stored] functions**. A stored procedure is invoked using the `CALL` statement. A procedure does not have a return value but can modify its parameters for later inspection by the caller. It can also generate result sets to be returned to the client program. A stored function is used much like a built-in function. you invoke it in an expression and it returns a value during expression evaluation.
>
> **Triggers.** A trigger is a named database object that is associated with a table and that is activated when a particular event occurs for the table, such as an insert or update.
>
> **Events.** An event is a task that the server runs according to schedule.
>
> <sup>— http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-programs-views.html</sup>

This excludes anything else you might do as a query, including server-side prepared statements and [multiple statement execution](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html).

It is slightly inaccurate but in general it holds that stored procedures have the fullest functionality, having generally fewer [restrictions on the kinds of things you can do](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-program-restrictions.html), but the 4 types of stored programs have a lot of commonality.

When a stored program can be expressed without using any semicolons, such as...

```
CREATE TRIGGER t1_ai AFTER INSERT ON t1 FOR EACH ROW DELETE FROM t2 WHERE t2.id = NEW.id;
```

...then the stored program does not require a `BEGIN`/`END` block.  Just about anything more complicated is essentially a [`compound statement`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-compound-statements.html) and has to be surrounded by a `BEGIN`/`END`, and this is the only place a `HANDLER` can be used.

These blocks can be nested within the body of a single stored program, and, in all but the simplest cases, every stored program has at least one -- the outermost one.

A `HANDLER`'s scope is the outermost block that includes the handler's declaration, and any blocks within that block that do not have a handler that could catch the condition instead.  Under no circumstance can a handler catch a condition that occurs before the beginning or after the end of the block where it is declared.

A `HANDLER`'s scope *also* includes anything done by the program while the handler is in scope, which could include calling other stored procedures or functions that don't have handlers of their own for the same conditions.

When a `CONTINUE` handler fires because the specified condition occurred, the statement specified by the handler declaration (see below) is executed, and then *program execution continues, gracefully, at the next statement after the statement that caused the exception, wherever that happened to be.*  The constraint here, of course, is that it can only have been somewhere that the handler was in scope.  It's not uncommon to use an otherwise-unnecessary `BEGIN`/`END` block strictly for the purpose of keeping a handler in scope for just a single statement or small number of statements, when it would be inappropriate for the handler to linger and catch conditions that shouldn't be caught.

In contrast to a `CONTINUE` handler, when an `EXIT` handler fires, the statement specified by the handler (see below) is executed, and then program execution continues after the `END` at the bottom of the block where the handler was declared.  If this is the `END` at the end of a procedure, the procedure terminates, gracefully, since the error was handled by the handler.  If the procedure was called by another procedure, control returns to the calling procedure.

Either way, the handler executes "a statement" before execution continues at the appropriate point.  "A statement" can be simple,

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET @something_happened = 1;
```

or compound (with a `BEGIN`/`END`).

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION BEGIN SET @foo = 1; DELETE FROM t1; ROLLBACK; END;
```

In the former case, simple statements are sometimes used to set variables that code elsewhere, *later* can use to detect that the condition occurred and react accordingly at the appropriate time, rather than immediately when the handler fires.